# How to integrate Fluent Validation into an ASP.Net Core MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to integrate Fluent Validation 11 into an ASP.Net Core MVC 7 project, but I'm having trouble getting it to work properly. I've installed the FluentValidation.AspNetCore package and added the necessary services in Program.cs file.

```
...
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ContactManagerContext>(...);

builder.Services.AddIdentity<...>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<...>()
    .AddSignInManager();

builder.Services.AddFluentValidationAutoValidation();
builder.Services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Program>();

var app = builder.Build();
...
```

And, I did already define my AbstractValidator :

```
...
public class LogInVM {
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; } = false;

    public class Validator : AbstractValidator<LogInVM> {
        public Validator() {
            RuleFor(vm => vm.UserName).NotNull().NotEmpty()
                .WithMessage("Please provide an UserName.");

            RuleFor(vm => vm.Password)NotNull().NotEmpty()
                .WithMessage("Please provide a Password.");
        }
    }
}
...
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

### UPDATE 01

This is where I try to validate the ViewModel.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> LogIn(LogInVM vm, string? returnUrl = null) {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        return View(vm);
    }

    ...
}
```

### UPDATE 02

I was mistaking, I did successfuly enable Fluent Validation into my project, but I wasn't able to disable the default validation behavior of ASP.Net Core Mvc. See the error messages returned to understand.

[image]

Comment: Could you post the code of the action where the validator doesn't work?   

The validator will be called directly when an action, that takes LogInVM as parameter, is invoked (eg. `public [HttpPost] public ActionResult LoginPost(LogInVM model)`). I also suggest to move the Validator class outside of LogInVM class definition and call it LogInVMValidator, normally validator class resides in a class by itself.

Comment: Hi @RobertoFerraris, Thank you for your quick response. I agree that it is usually better to keep the model and validation class separate, but in this case, I need to combine them for the sake of readability. Otherwise, as you can see in my Update 01, I have included the action code where I automatically use the abstract validator by calling `ModelState.IsValid`. I look forward to your reply. ;)

Comment: I tried your code and it seems to work (you can find the [code on github](https://github.com/roby70/TestFluentValidation_75561807)). What do you mean to work properly? In debug did you find IsValid to true?

Comment: After some testing, you were right; my code works. However, the default validation behavior of ASP.Net Core MVC was not overridden (as of update 02). I would like the error message defined in the abstract validator to be the one shown to the user. I have tried to configure Fluent Validation to override it, but none of my previous attempts have been successful.

Comment: It depends on the fact that UserName and Password are not nullable, so ASP.NET find them empty and return directly this error. 
Define them as `string?` instead of `string`, and at this point FluentValidation will be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

I also created a ASP.Net Core MVC project and faced this problem like you.

When we use fluent validations, its validations error messages is added over the default validations.

Because of this we only see the default error messages.

So, to overcome this problem you can clear default validations.

```
 builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options => options.ModelValidatorProviders.Clear());
```

After this you will see that your error messages will be displayed.